# Free Blue-ray Movie Player

Tags: windows, gratis, video, media-player

I am trying to find a good, free blu-ray movie player for my computer running Windows 8...

Here are my current Options which I have looked into already:

1. VLC Player 2.1 does support Blu-ray, but is has a lot of work to do... I have tried the CODEC work around for support also
2. CyberLinks PowerDVD is good, for the trail, but you have to pay for it for full access to features
3. Media Player is $69 addon with Windows 8 and 8.1

Am I missing something about VLC player? Or is there a better recommendation for me?

Comment: Apart of being BD players and that works in windows, what else you look for?

Comment: I'm looking for an alternitive to VLC and having to pay these other two options?

Comment: Try KM player. I think it supports blu-ray videos.

Comment: @Traven Have you followed the instructions at http://vlc-bluray.whoknowsmy.name/ ?

Comment: What exactly are the problem you encounter with VLC?

Comment: @Cornelius I have tried all of that.

Comment: And the issue is of DRM, or Copyrights on the DVD to keep Bluray from being played a lot from the computer, from what I am reading. The Bluray is encoded so we can't do that as easily as we'd like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see you've been having trouble.

Check out PotPlayer.
Supports Windows 8 perfectly, too. :)

http://www.videohelp.com/tools/PotPlayer

Answer (score 2):

The **Blu-ray playback addon** [(direct download link)](http://vlc-bluray.whoknowsmy.name/files/KEYDB.cfg) pack for VLC may be what you are looking for. See [here](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=105955) for instructions on how to use it.

- It will make Blu-ray support in VLC just work.
- It is free as in freedom and gratis.
- It works well for Windows 8, reportedly better than Media Player (see above instructions).

Recommanding VLC for someone asking for an alternative to VLC might sound awkward, but I'm pretty confident the Blu-ray addon will allow you to make full use of this beautiful piece of software.

Comment: I have already tried all of the VLC work arounds, such as the one you have posted. Bluray support is very limited right now with DRM issues.

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://vlc-bluray.whoknowsmy.name/)? It works for me on some Blu-ray PotPlayer fails to read, but who knows, the magic of Blu-rays...